# Не работает ссылка после pjax?

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Здравствуйте!
На странице есть GridView обернутый в pjax с фильтрами.
На каждую запись добавлена ссылка:

```
<?= GridView::widget([  
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,  
        'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {  
            return [  
                'data-pjax' => 0,  
                'data-method' => 'post',  
                'data-url' => Url::to(['test', 'result_id' => $model->id]),  
            ];   
        },
```

Но, ссылка работает только если не использовать Pjax, если сработал фильтр или пагинация без перезагрузки, то ссылка остается на каждой записи, но она не кликабельная. Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: может быть всё что угодно. смотрите в панели разработчика на вкладки console и network. скорее всего 500е ошибки в контроллере Test на экшене Index

Comment: У вас какой-то скрипт подключен, который переходит по `data-url`? Если да, то все дело в том, что скрипт не перезагружается после обновления Pjax, следовательно не видит ваши подгружаемые записи. Дополните ваш вопрос кодом

Comment: А если все таки первый вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка должна перезагружать Pjax? или она просто должна вести на другую страницу с перезагрузкой? Если 2ой вариант, то Вероятно Ваш Pjax слушает все теги `a`, поэтому новые ссылки и не работают, точнее они работают, но их события перехватываются Pjax'ом, Вам нужно отключить его обработку для конкретно этих ссылок. Просто добавьте `data-pjax=0` для каждой ссылки таким образом

```
<?= GridView::widget([  
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,  
        'rowOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $grid) {  
            return [   
                'data-method' => 'post',  
                'data-url' => Url::to(['test', 'result_id' => $model->id, 'data-pjax' => 0]),  
            ];   
        },
```

Если это не то, что Вам нужно, то дополните вопрос